# Int passed into Intent but Android studio is saying that I passed a String instead

Tags: android

I pasased an int array into my intent but Android studio is saying :

error: method getIntExtra in class Intent cannot be applied to given types;
img = getIntent().getIntExtra("myImg");
^
required: String,int
found: String
reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length

String int found: String reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length

The Adapter Code:

```
public class myAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<myAdapter.MyViewHolder> {


String names[],descriptions[];
Context context;
int images[];


public myAdapter(Context ct, String nm[], String des[], int img[] ){
    names=nm;
    descriptions=des;
    images=img;
    context=ct;
}


@NonNull
@Override
public myAdapter.MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {



      LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.recycle_row, parent, false);
        return new MyViewHolder(view);
    }

    //
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull myAdapter.MyViewHolder holder,int position) {
//Setting the text to the textView from the names array
        holder.resTitle.setText(names[position]);
        holder.myImg.setImageResource(images[position]);
        //onclick listener for the rows
        holder.mylayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            //might have to use getContext Here
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(context, cuisineInformationActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("Name", names[position]);
                intent.putExtra("Description", descriptions[position]);
                intent.putExtra("myImg", images[position]);
                context.startActivity(intent);

            }
```

The Activity class:

```
    //this activity will react to a click on the recycleview in cuisineFragment and will show fruther information about that particular restaurant
public class cuisineInformationActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    ImageView Imageview;
    TextView name,description;
    String nm, ds;
    int img;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_cuisine_information);

        Imageview = findViewById(R.id.restActImgview);
        name = findViewById(R.id.restActName);
        description = findViewById(R.id.restActDesc);

        getData();
        setData();


    }

//getting the data from intent
    private void getData() {
        if (getIntent().hasExtra("Name") && getIntent().hasExtra("Description") && getIntent().hasExtra("myImg") ){
            nm = getIntent().getStringExtra("Name");
            ds = getIntent().getStringExtra("Description");
            img = getIntent().getIntExtra("myImg");

        } else{
            Toast.makeText(this,"No data was found",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getIntExtra()` [takes two parameters](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent?hl=en#getIntExtra(java.lang.String,%20int)):

- The name of the extra
- A default value to return if the extra is missing

You are only providing one parameter: the name. So, add a second parameter, which is your default value, such as `img = getIntent().getIntExtra("myImg", -1);`.

Comment: Also you're reading the error wrong - it says `required: String,int` meaning it takes two parameters, i.e. `getIntExtra(String, int)`. `found: String` means it only found a single `String` parameter. `reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length` is hopefully obvious now ;)

Comment: And an `IntArrayExtra` and an `IntExtra` are *not* the same thing! Make sure you're using the correct methods for whichever type you're actually using, an array or a single `int`

Comment: I am passing images[position] that why i use IntExtra instead of IntArrayExtra. i tried to add the second parameter and it fixed the error but my app still crashes when i click on the navbar for that fragment

Comment: Note: /Users/milanlabus/Documents/AndroidDev/BelgradeApp2/app/src/main/java/com/example/belgradeapp/MainActivity.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.

Comment: public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {


    BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        bottomNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.bottomNavigationView);
        bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
        bottomNavigationView.setSelectedItemId(R.id.home);

    }
    homeFra

Comment: Its depricating the.  .setOnNavigationItemSelectedListerener(this)

Comment: @JoeWilliams: "it fixed the error but my app still crashes when i click on the navbar for that fragment" -- then ask a separate Stack Overflow question with a new [mcve] showing the new [stack trace](https://commonsware.com/Jetpack/pages/chap-debug-001.html) and the code associated with that crash.